# ngx-intl-tel-input for phone number input not working

Tags: angular

I use ngx-intl-tel-input and I get this error. Someone can help me? thank you

```
core.js:4002 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownConfig]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BsDropdownConfig!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BsDropdownDirective -> BsDropdownConfig]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for BsDropdownConfig!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:725)
    at resolveToken (core.js:11918)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:11862)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:11764)
    at resolveToken (core.js:11918)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:11862)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:11764)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:20234)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:20905)
    at resolveDep (core.js:21276)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at zone.js:913
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1693)
defaultErrorLogger
```